# 502 error on file upload (angular) to node app on nginx

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nginx

I've been banging my head over this issue for a couple of days now. The issue is whenever a file (.pdf) is uploaded from the frontend (angular), I immediately see an error in the console:

[image]

**Now I can definitely eliminate the chance of this being a CORS issue as all the other APIs (GET/POST/PUT) are working just fine, only this upload api fails.**

I'm able to see this error in nginx logs:

```
2018/06/08 03:08:13 [error] 30437#30437: *9 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***.***.*.*, server: abc.com, request: "POST /docupload HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/docupload", host: "abc.com", referrer: "https://*.com/"
```

Also, after this happens, the node server just silently restarts. No errors at all.

Below is the nginx config:

```
server {
  server_name abc.com;
  location / {
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  Host       $http_host;
    proxy_pass        http://node;
  }
}

upstream node {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

I've tried almost every solution available on the internet but nothing seems to work out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can u try installing cors plugin and redo the same? This does not look to be a client issue and I doubt that server is not capable to handle your request.

Link to the plugin here -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: The ```cors``` npm package is already installed and working fine. The thing is all other apis are working just fine.

Comment: Try to upload using postman and let me know if you get the same error

Comment: There are no errors if I'm using postman or running the whole project locally and everything works normally.

Comment: Can you try putting these two below statements and see if works?

proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_buffering off;

Referenced from : https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/5706#issuecomment-294433262

Comment: It's still the same.

Comment: Maybe CORS is working for some HTTP methods but not all. If it is working for API, it doesn't mean it will work for everything else.

Can you post your http request information (from Chrome), alternatively you can use fiddler as well.